# MySQL error: 'order by timestamp desc limit 1' at line 5

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying couple of days run script "showcalendar.php" from Rowland Carson in MRBS calendar. I went through some errors with database, but now stuck by these:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order by timestamp desc limit 1' at line 5"

I use MRBS 1.4.11, Apache/2.2.16 (Debian), MySQL client version: 5.1.66.
I found this theme: [display todays bookings from mysql mrbs calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795360/display-todays-bookings-from-mysql-mrbs-calendar)
also checked some infos on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp and made gogolresearch
but no progress. Please could You help me or give me advice for right direction?
Thank You very much for Your time and energy:)

```
$conn = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass)

or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("mrbs", $conn)  or die(mysql_error());



$get_entries = "select timestamp

from $bookings

order by timestamp desc

limit 1

"

;

$entries_result = mysql_query($get_entries) or die(mysql_error());

$data_row = mysql_fetch_object($entries_result);

$last_changed = $data_row->timestamp;



$get_rooms = "select *

from $rooms

order by id

"

;

$rooms_result = mysql_query($get_rooms) or die(mysql_error());

$n_rooms = mysql_num_rows($rooms_result);

$n_cols = $n_rooms + 1;



$booking_block = "<TABLE align=center BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=5>\n";

$booking_block .= "<tr><td colspan=".$n_cols.">";

$booking_block .= "Room bookings for week beginning ";

$booking_block .= $startingDateArray['mday']." ";

$booking_block .= $startingDateArray['month']." ";

$booking_block .= $startingDateArray['year']." ";

$booking_block .= "(Last change to any booking was made ";

$booking_block .= $last_changed;

$booking_block .= ")</td></tr>\n";

$booking_block .= "<tr><td align=right>".$startYear."</td>\n";



while ($rooms = mysql_fetch_array($rooms_result, MYSQL_ASSOC))

{

$booking_block .= "<td>";

$booking_block .= $rooms['room_name'];

$booking_block .= "</td>";

}

$booking_block .= "</tr>\n";



for ($day_number = 0; $day_number <= 6; $day_number++)

{

$booking_block .= "<tr>\n";

$booking_block .= "<td align=right valign=top>";

$endOfDay = $theTimestamp + ONE_DAY;

$theDateArray = getdate($theTimestamp);

if ($theDateArray['year'] != $startYear)

{

    $startYear = $theDateArray['year'];

    $booking_block .= $startYear."<br>";

}

$booking_block .= date("D d M", $theTimestamp)."</td>\n";



for ($room_number = 1; $room_number <= $n_rooms; $room_number++)

{

    $get_bookings = "select *

        from $bookings

        where start_time >= $theTimestamp

        and start_time <= $endOfDay

        and room_id = $room_number

        order by start_time

        "

        ;

    $bookings_result = mysql_query($get_bookings) or die(mysql_error());

    $booking_block .= "<td valign=top>";

    if (mysql_num_rows($bookings_result) > 0)

    {

        while ($booking_entry = mysql_fetch_array($bookings_result, MYSQL_ASSOC))

        {

            $booking_block .= date("H:i", $booking_entry['start_time']);

            $booking_block .= "-";

            $booking_block .= date("H:i", $booking_entry['end_time']);

            $booking_block .= " ";

            $booking_block .= $booking_entry['name'];

            $booking_block .= "<br>\n";

        }

    }

    else

    {

        $booking_block .= "<br>";

    }

    $booking_block .= "</td>";

}

$booking_block .= "</tr>\n";

$theTimestamp = $theTimestamp + ONE_DAY;

}



$booking_block .= "<tr><td colspan=".$n_cols." align=right>";

$booking_block .= "This web page rendered at ";

$booking_block .= sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d",

                        $nowArray['hours'],

                        $nowArray['minutes'],

                        $nowArray['seconds']);

$booking_block .= " on ";

$booking_block .= $nowArray['mday']." ";

$booking_block .= $nowArray['month']." ";

$booking_block .= $nowArray['year']." ";



$booking_block .= "</table>\n";
```

Comment: I hate to be that guy but you shouldn't be using mysql. You should see this once you solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Thank you! Will check these theme and hope will soon learn.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's error snippets start at the point of the query AFTER where the error occurred. Since you're getting `order by ...` in the error output, that means the error was right before that point, which probably means `$bookings` is undefined, and your query looks like

```
SELECT timestamp
FROM
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Note the lack of a table name. an `echo $get_entries` will confirm that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately $bookings is defined...What can it be next?

Comment: so what value IS in there? if it's a non-valid field name, like `Stuff To do`, then you'd have to quote that whole value to make it a "legal" table name.

Comment: The value is $bookings = "mrbs_entry" ()

Comment: The value is $bookings = "mrbs_entry"  (mrbs_entry= table name in db)